# Multi-Step forms as classic multiple choice form or chatbot?

Tags: questionnaire, chatbots

I'm currently working on a landingpage that includes a digital user advisor where they can find out more about topics that fit to their life/work conditions.

**Example:**
Company X is working in laboratory equipment and wants to upsell more to the costumer. The costumer doesn't know that company X is also selling workwear and furniture. So through a questionnaire the company wants to find out what the user is interested in and if the other offers fit his needs.

The questionnaire starts with the question if the costumer works or owns a lab. If the lab is equipped with ergonomic furniture and safety apparel and so on. In the end the costumer gets a result with a summary, recommendations and links.

**Question:**
I was asking myself if there is any study or if anyone has experiences in implementing this the most valuable way for the user. With the rise of chatbots and chat CRM I was wondering if this form/questionnaire would be more trustworthy in a messenger/chat design, with typing animation and so on, especially because most of the traffic is mobile. Or whether it actually does not matter.

I'm happy about any recommendation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would be an ideal UX research project. you need to find out what your particular users would prefer in your particular situation. No one here will be able to give you a definitive answer - the only people qualified to do that are your users. You could run some surveys about other sites/products they use, build both solutions and run A-B tests, build them as prototypes and run some user testing sessions... However you do it, you need to find out from your users what would be most valuable to them

Answer (score 0):

### Product recommendation engine

##### Personalized product recommendations based on behavioral data

I don't know how up-to-date your application is, but in practically most apps there is a `you might also be interested in` feature after making the first purchase. This not only avoids any annoying and absurd user questionnaires but even gets more results than ten questions can give.

On the corner of my house, there's a supermarket that, without being a large chain, after buying a kilogram of tomatoes, is incredible the reading it has made of my behavior as a customer and the offers it gave me related to my lifestyle without even knowing who I am.

> P**roduct recommendation engines** analyze data about shoppers to learn exactly what types of products and offerings interest them. Based on search behavior and product preferences, they serve up contextually relevant offers and product options that appeal to individual shoppers — and help drive sales.

<sub>*Source [salesforce.com](https://www.salesforce.com/resources/articles/what-is-product-recommendation-engine/#:%7E:text=Product%20recommendation%20engines%20analyze%20data,shoppers%20%E2%80%94%20and%20help%20drive%20sales.)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks for you answer! That would make sense if the customer would be in the funnel and finishes an order. For this case the customer is on landing page that is for awareness purposes only and I want to find out what they are interested in and what offer would fit to them. It’s more a question of visual implementation and I wonder if there is anything that says that customers rely more on virtual chats then progress bar questionnaires.